# Receiving error in react router dom while using nested routes in vitejs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

When I run my react project with `vite dev`, my project runs fine. After running `vite build && vite preview` I get an error with my app.

Here's the error

```
index-26685beb.js:4306 Error
    at invariant (App-1ae6b17c.js:34:11)
    at useRoutes (App-1ae6b17c.js:619:27)
    at Routes (App-1ae6b17c.js:847:10)
    at Xh (index-26685beb.js:3841:7)
    at Wk (index-26685beb.js:6937:11)
```

The error message is not provided and I had to do some digging in my dependencies. I found that it was failing here in my react-router-dom dependency:

```js
function useRoutes(routes, locationArg) {
  !useInRouterContext() ? invariant(false) : void 0; <-- fails here at invariant() call
  let {
    navigator
  } = reactExports.useContext(NavigationContext);
  ...
```

I think this might have to do that I have nested routes in my project. Here's how it looks

`App.jsx`

```js
const Project = () => {
  const loc = useParams();
  const { export: componentexport } = projectMap[loc.id];
  const Component = lazy(componentexport);
  return (
     <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        < Component />
     </Suspense >
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={HOME.to} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path={PROJECTS.to} element={<Projects />} />
        <Route path={LOADING.to} element={<Loading />} />
        <Route path="/projects/:id/*" element={<Project />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And here's one of the project components

```js
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Root />}>
        <Route path='' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes >
  )
}
```

I noticed when I remove the routes entirely from the component placed in `<Project/>` my app works fine. Am I allowed to use nested routes for builds? Should I be setting up my vite config a certain way?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was occurring because of the `vite build` step in this case. I have my portfolio and I have my project in 2 separate directories, each with their own downloaded dependencies

```
portfolio: Code/portfolio
project1: Code/project1
```

What I was doing was importing `../../project1/src/App.jsx` into my portfolio to use as a component. However, in the build step dependencies are optimized but I was using `react-router-dom` in both projects. When I ran a `sourcemap` for my build I found the following:

```json
sources = [
    ...,
    "../../node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js",
    "../../node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js",
    "../../node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js",
    "../../src/utils/mainRoutes.js",
    "../../../../polus-site/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js",
    "../../../../polus-site/node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js",
    ...,
  ]
```

So it looks like I have duplicated the `react-router-dom` dependency bundle and have two separate instances of `react-router-dom` in my build.

This being the case, I updated my build files to point to the correct version of `react-router-dom` that I was using e.g. if there was an instance of `useRoutes$1` and `useRoutes` I would switch all cases to use `useRoutes$1` since this was using my portfolio's router.

This is not necessarily an answer since I think there is a build config to fix this, but for now this is my workaround to deploy the portfolio